# Why I get different output when I run the same code but different name?

Tags: python

When I run my code using `print(xdata[0:1, 0:1, :])`I got the fist line of array but when i run using `print(state)` I got a line of array which contain in xdata but I don't know why I got that  .

```
def load_data(test=False):
    #prices = pd.read_pickle('data/OILWTI_1day.pkl')
    #prices = pd.read_pickle('data/EURUSD_1day.pkl')
    #prices.rename(columns={'Value': 'close'}, inplace=True)
    prices = pd.read_pickle('D:\data/XBTEUR_1day.pkl')
    prices.rename(columns={'Open': 'open', 'High': 'high', 'Low': 'low', 'Close': 'close', 'Volume (BTC)': 'volume'}, inplace=True)

    x_train = prices.iloc[-2000:-300,]
    x_test= prices.iloc[-2000:,]
    if test:
        return x_test
    else:
        return x_train

def init_state(indata, test=False):
    close = indata['close'].values
    diff = np.diff(close)
    diff = np.insert(diff, 0, 0)
    sma15 = SMA(indata, timeperiod=15)
    sma60 = SMA(indata, timeperiod=60)
    rsi = RSI(indata, timeperiod=14)
    atr = ATR(indata, timeperiod=14)

    #--- Preprocess data
    xdata = np.column_stack((close, diff, sma15, close-sma15, sma15-sma60, rsi, atr))

    xdata = np.nan_to_num(xdata)
    if test == False:
        scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
        xdata = np.expand_dims(scaler.fit_transform(xdata), axis=1)
        joblib.dump(scaler, 'D:\data/scaler.pkl')
    elif test == True:
        scaler = joblib.load('D:\data/scaler.pkl')
        xdata = np.expand_dims(scaler.fit_transform(xdata), axis=1)
    state = xdata[0:1, 0:1, :]

    return state, xdata, close

indata = load_data(test=True)
A = init_state(indata, test=False)
print(xdata[0:1, 0:1, :])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing your return values in a reasonable way.  You store all three values to `A`, and then access `xdata`.  It's unclear why the latter is even defined at the global scope, and if it is, it's just some left-over from elsewhere.  Use `state, xdata, close = init_state(...)` instead of `A = ...`, and everything should work like exepected.

Comment: Thank you so much you save my time.